# Parse Subclassing Object - Access to array Attribute

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, subclassing

this is the scenario:

I would to fill a uitabliview with an array stored within the attribute in a object that extends PFObject

Something didn't work like I expected. Within the viewDidload method of my uitableviewcontroller I populated the evento:Event object.

this is what I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    println("PartecipantList viewDidLoad \(evento?)")
    println("PartecipantList viewDidLoad \(evento?.partecipants)")
}
```

and the result:

```
PartecipantList viewDidLoad Optional(<Event: 0x156a1370, objectId: sKSox7JrQb, localId: (null)> {
createdBy = "<PFUser: 0x156b97e0, objectId: 97BcwWQRSk>";
endAt = "2014-12-14 10:48:00 +0000";
partecipants =     (
    "<Partecipant: 0x155a60c0, objectId: aI4bgpHuhG, localId: (null)> {\n    email = \"email_1@dominomail.ss\";\n    event = \"<Event: 0x156b91d0, objectId: sKSox7JrQb>\";\n    nickname = \"nickname_1\";\n}",
    "<Partecipant: 0x155a70a0, objectId: wN71hDJMBY, localId: (null)> {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x155a7280>\";\n    email = \"email_3@gmail.com\";\n    event = \"<Event: 0x155a6a00, objectId: sKSox7JrQb>\";\n    nickname = pippo;\n}",
    "<Partecipant: 0x155a7f60, objectId: dBLPN2nMy2, localId: (null)> {\n    email = \"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com\";\n    event = \"<Event: 0x155a6920, objectId: sKSox7JrQb>\";\n    nickname = nickname_2;\n}"
);
startAt = "2014-12-03 10:47:00 +0000";
title = "evento di completo";
total = "12.44";
})
```

and for a reason I didn't get yet:

```
PartecipantList viewDidLoad Optional([])
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

To be exhaustive, this is Event Object:

```
class Event:PFObject,PFSubclassing {
    override class func load() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Event"
    }

    dynamic var createdBy:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    dynamic var title:String = "Evento"
    dynamic var startAt:NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var endAt:NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var total:Double = 0.0
    dynamic var partecipants:[Partecipant] = []

}
```

**[UPDATE]**

i make some other test and using

```
    if var partecipants = self.evento?.objectForKey("partecipants")  as? [AnyObject]{
        println("PartecipantList viewDidLoad \(partecipants.count)" )
    }
```

it worked.

It seems  something related to the access to class attribute. I tried also without dynamic keyword but the result was the same.
does somebody have any explanation please?

Comment: Please explain what is not working.

Comment: please read again the post. 
It's related to access to participants attribute for Event class. within the output of the object you can see participants array filled, but the output of the array is empty, accessing directly to attribute

Comment: You have not explained what does not work. You can access participants via the optional clause. What is the problem?

Comment: that seeing the output of the object, participants is filled. but when I try to access to attribute the array is empty. I believed that the code was clear, sorry. I hope now is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused about optionals in Swift and what they print to the console. The output is far from intuitive.

You get `Optional([])` if the optional value is `nil`. If it is populated, it should  not surprise you to see the data in the log statements, including its attributes.

You state that the second test works. That is exactly how the extraction of data from a collection is done in Swift. It ensures that the key is present and returns the expected value. Use this data to populate your table view.

Comment: what you say about Optional make me confused. I made a test declaring 

    var stringOptional:String?
    var myString:String = "pippo", I populate the 'optional' (it's not nil): stringOptional = "it's a real value"
 and then I generate the output for both: println("stringOptional: \(stringOptional)") and  println("myString: \(myString)").
here the result: stringOptional: Optional("it\'s a real value") and 
myString: pippo.
Here I'm not surprised, 'cause the output is as I expected. I think that Optional is referred to the attribute declared as 'it could be also nil', so you have to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution or maybe a trick:

I seen that using @NSManaged instead of dynamic keyword when I declaring the class attributes I achieve the desired result: to have access to the attribute.
so declaring Event in this way I can subclass PFObject as I desire.

this also means that it will introduce a dependency of CoreData

```
class Event:PFObject,PFSubclassing {
    override class func load() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Event"
    }

    @NSManaged var createdBy:PFUser
    @NSManaged var title:String
    @NSManaged var startAt:NSDate
    @NSManaged var endAt:NSDate
    @NSManaged var total:Double
    @NSManaged var partecipants:[Partecipant] 
}
```

I don't know if it is something that it should be fixed on Parse but I hope they take care about this. the framework is really good.